# Edgeguides' Getting Started with Rails template missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just began learning ruby on rails and while going through the guide [link](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), I cannot change the page display in step 4.3

my routes.rb file looks precisely as recommended in the guide, having only two lines between the draw and its end:

```
get 'welcome/index' 
root 'welcome#index'
```

while my index.html.erb file looks like this:

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
```

yet when I load the `localhost:3000` page, it gives the error

> WelcomeController#index is missing a template for request formats:
>   text/html

even though the file `index.html.erb` is valid.
any suggestions for what could be the matter?

EDIT: Server log reads as follows:

```
Started GET "/welcome/index" for ::1 at 2020-02-12 15:19:39 -0500    (5.7ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*) Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1989)



ActionController::MissingExactTemplate (WelcomeController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html):

actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:45:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:196:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:51:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:837:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I have also tried continuing to follow the guide to step 5.1 and though all the errors appear as the guide says, the 'solution' at the end of that step still causes an error with template format.

Comment: show me config/routes.rb. I think there is some line includes `resources :articles`

Comment: Where is your `index.html.erb` file located? At the same location as the guide describes? (`app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`) Have you already tried restarting the server?

Comment: config/routes.rb does have resources :articles now for step 5.1, but was not prsent when the error occured for 4.3. the index.html.erb file is located precisely where it was generated and where the guide describes - app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

Comment: remove or comment that line. Rails checks if all routes are valid before process your requests.

Comment: @БуянбатЧойжилсүрэн that's nonsense. Rails does not check if all your routes have controllers and views when processing a request. It just attempts to find a  route that matches the request.

Comment: "yet when I load the localhost:3000 page" - what is the exact URL that you requested?

Comment: @max that is right.

Comment: I queried both http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3000/welcome/index

Comment: There is something missing or really off about this question. There is no possible way that we can reproduce that getting the root path or `/welcome/index ` will call `ArticlesController#new` given that set of routes. I would recommend you backtrack or start over.

Comment: Could you add the server log for the request in question to the post?